# HyperX microphone doesn't work (the sound works fine) on Pop OS

Tags: audio, microphone

So i'm on Pop!_OS 19.10 (it works the same way as Ubuntu for the sound)

I have a hyperX Headphone with a microphone, the sound works without any problem but my microphone don't (the microphone from the computer works also fine)

`Result of lspci | grep -i Audio :`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Alsamixer : [image]

And I can't choose any other imput for my microphone
Everything works fine on windows 10

Can anyone help me please ?